# Postgres query for applying groupBy to the top X rows based on created_on timestamp column?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table in Postgres:

**adjustments table**

- id (pk)
- property_id
- value
- created_on_utc

I would like to create a query that will get the top X most recent records based on the  created_on_utc column **and then** group and count the number of records for each property_id.

I tried the statement below, but I get an error:

`SELECT COUNT(a.id), property_id FROM adjustments as a GROUP BY a.property_id ORDER BY created_on_utc DESC; LIMIT 1000;`

Error:
SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "pa.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
Position: 87

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of following scripts.

With using CTE:

```
WITH recent_adjustments AS (
    SELECT id, property_id
    FROM adjustments
    ORDER BY created_on_utc DESC
    LIMIT 1000
)
SELECT 
    property_id, 
    COUNT(id) AS record_count
FROM 
    recent_adjustments
GROUP BY 
    property_id;
```

Without using CTE:

```
SELECT 
    property_id, 
    COUNT(id) AS record_count
FROM 
    (SELECT id, property_id
     FROM adjustments
     ORDER BY created_on_utc DESC
     LIMIT 1000) AS recent_adjustments
GROUP BY 
    property_id;
```